# C# - RSACryptoServiceProvider - Error: Bad Data

Tags: c#, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm trying to run an RSA decryption with C#.

My code:

```
byte[] n = BigInteger.Parse("3104649130901425335933838103517383").ToByteArray();
byte[] p = BigInteger.Parse("49662237675630289").ToByteArray();
byte[] q = BigInteger.Parse("62515288803124247").ToByteArray();
byte[] e = BigInteger.Parse("65537").ToByteArray();
byte[] d = BigInteger.Parse("1427000713644866747260499795119265").ToByteArray();
byte[] dp = BigInteger.Parse("15085765714732865").ToByteArray();
byte[] dq = BigInteger.Parse("1326865232237451").ToByteArray();
byte[] iq = BigInteger.Parse("5777070651124236").ToByteArray();

RSAParameters rsaparams = new RSAParameters();
rsaparams.P = p;
rsaparams.Q = q;
rsaparams.Modulus = n;
rsaparams.Exponent = e;
rsaparams.D = d;
rsaparams.DP = dp;
rsaparams.DQ = dq;
rsaparams.InverseQ = iq;

RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
csp.ImportParameters(rsaparams);
```

When i run it, I get this error:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently `RSAParameters` expects its component byte[] arrays to be in big-endian format. Thus you must reverse the bytes in each of your byte arrays you obtained from `BigInteger.ToByteArray()`. An example in-place reverse method is:

```
    public static void reverse (ref byte[] x)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = x.Length - 1;
        while (i < j)
        {
            byte t = x [i];
            x [i] = x [j];
            x [j] = t;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it is not the solution.. The exception is still thrown.